# Client sends 500 Bytes, but server receives 244 Bytes - Socket Programming?

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to implement the `Stop-and-Wait ARQ` for `UDP`. According to the Stop-and-Wait conventions, I toggle my `ACK` between `0` and `1`.

A correct `ACK` is defined as a correct sequence number (either `0` or `1`) **AND** a correct message length.

The following snippets are my related parts of the code.

## Client Side

```
// transmission function
void str_cli(FILE *fp, int sockfd, long *len, struct sockaddr *addr, int addrlen)
{
    char *buf;
    long lsize, ci;
    char sends[DATALEN];
    struct ack_so ack;
    int n, slen;
    float time_inv = 0.0;
    struct timeval sendt, recvt;
    ci = 0;

    int prev_msg_acked = TRUE;
    int ack_number = 1;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    lsize = ftell (fp);
    rewind(fp);
    printf("The file length is %d bytes\n", (int)lsize);
    printf("the packet length is %d bytes\n", DATALEN);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file.
    buf = (char *) malloc(lsize);
    if (buf == NULL)
       exit (2);

    // copy the file into the buffer.
    fread(buf, 1, lsize, fp);

    // the whole file is loaded in the buffer
    buf[lsize] ='\0'; // append the end byte
    gettimeofday(&sendt, NULL); // get the current time
    while(ci <= lsize)
    {
        if (prev_msg_acked) // only transmits when previous message has been acknowledged
        {
            if ((lsize+1-ci) <= DATALEN) // final string
                slen = lsize+1-ci;
            else // send message of length DATALEN
                slen = DATALEN;
            memcpy(sends, (buf+ci), slen);

            /*************** SEND MESSAGE ***************/
            if((n = sendto(sockfd, &sends, strlen(sends), 0, addr, addrlen)) == -1) {
                printf("send error!\n"); // send the data
                exit(1);
            }

            // update the expected ACK number
            if (ack_number == 1)
                ack_number = 0;
            else
                ack_number = 1;

            ci += slen;
        }

        /*************** RECEIVE ACK ***************/
        if ((n = recvfrom(sockfd, &ack, 2, 0, addr, &addrlen)) == -1)
        {
            printf("error when receiving\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (ack.num != ack_number || ack.len != slen) // ACK wrong
        {
            printf("%i %i expected\n", ack_number, strlen(sends));
            printf("%i %i received\n", ack.num, ack.len);
            printf("ACK check fails, retransmission...\n");
            prev_msg_acked = FALSE;
        }
        else
            prev_msg_acked = TRUE;
    }
}
```

## Server Side

```
// transmitting and receiving function
void str_ser(int sockfd, int *ack_number)
{   
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    char recvs[DATALEN];
    int end = 0, n = 0;
    long lseek = 0;
    struct ack_so ack;

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    printf("receiving data!\n");

    while(!end)
    {
        // receive the packet
        if ((n = recvfrom(sockfd, &recvs, DATALEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &len)) == -1)
        {
            printf("error when receiving\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // toggle the ack_number
        if (*ack_number == 1)
            *ack_number = 0;
        else
            *ack_number = 1;

        // if the last bit of the received string is the EoF
        if (recvs[n-1] == '\0')
        {
            end = 1;
            n--;
        }

        memcpy((buf+lseek), recvs, n);
        lseek += n;

        // up to here, successfully received a packet
        // send ACK back
        ack.num = *ack_number;
        ack.len = strlen(recvs);
        printf("%i %i as ACK sent\n", ack.num, ack.len);
        if ((n = sendto(sockfd, &ack, 2, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, len)) == -1)
        {
            printf("ACK send error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if ((fp = fopen ("myUDPreceive.txt", "wt")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File doesn't exit\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fwrite (buf, 1, lseek, fp); //write data into file
    fclose(fp);
    printf("A file has been successfully received!\nThe total data received is %d bytes\n", (int)lseek);
}
```

**With this implementation, I ended up with the following results:**

## Client Side Results

```
$ ./cli localhost
The file length is 59792 bytes
the packet length is 500 bytes
0 500 expected
0 244 received
ACK check fails, retransmission...
```

## Server Side Results

```
$ ./ser
receiving data!
0 244 as ACK sent
```

As can be seen, the client sends out a message of length `500`, and thus expects an `ACK` to be `0 500`. However, the server receives a message of length `244`, and sends back an `ACK` `0 244`. Since they do not match, the current implementation simply stops there.

Why would this length difference happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not be using `strlen` to determine the length of the data on either end, as that will prevent you from being able to send any binary data. Also, on the server it looks like you are expecting there to only be a 0 byte at the end of the data if it is the end of the file, so your `strlen` call is going to give you unreliable results in all other cases as well. Use the return value of `recvfrom` to determine how much data you received.

Another issue with your code is this:

```
buf = (char *) malloc(lsize);
...
buf[lsize] ='\0'; // append the end byte
```

You're allocating a memory buffer equal to the size of your file, and then setting a 0 byte past the end of that memory, which will cause you problems in the long-run. You should allocate an extra byte for that, so make it:

```
buf = (char *) malloc(lsize+1);
...
buf[lsize] ='\0'; // append the end byte
```

**Update:**

After reviewing your full code, I see the real problem:

```
struct ack_so
{
    uint8_t num; // the sequence number
    uint8_t len; // the packet length
};
```

`ack_so::len` is an 8-bit unsigned integer, which has a value range of 0-255, so 500 will overflow that value, giving you 244.

You should make `len` a `uint32_t`

Comment: Makes much sense, but I do not know why problem remains after I made the modifications.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure about your `sends`. [The documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html) says the 2nd argument should be a pointer instead of a variable, right? I still think it should be `&sends`.

Comment: Oh I see! Makes sense. But as I said, the error remains... The full code is available here: [client](http://pastie.org/private/kkz51bpdeywihvuu8gvda), [server](http://pastie.org/private/y3qjvbbjllspsaxoeq0dqg) and [header](http://pastie.org/private/rwjh9gcc485pkrdrsno3q). With the full codes, I think you are able to copy-n-paste-n-run it on your computer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I posted an update to my answer. The problem is with your `ack_so` structure. len is an 8-bit unsigned integer, which cannot hold a value greater than 255.

Answer (score 3):

In your client, you are doing

```
sendto(sockfd, &sends, strlen(sends), 0, addr, addrlen)
```

what you want is

```
sendto(sockfd, &sends, slen, 0, addr, addrlen)
```

strlen is problematic for two reasons:
(1) You do not null-terminate the buffer, and, more importantly,
(2) You are sending binary data which probably has a null byte as its 245 byte.

Rule of thumb: *never* use string functions on binary data.

Comment: And the same for `ack.len = strlen(recvs);`

Comment: So strange. What you said totally makes sense. But after I modify, the problem remains...